# BlackBerry: UnsupportedOperationException in payment sdk below 5.0 Simulator

Tags: blackberry

I am using payment sdk. It's work fine in 5.0 simulator but  below 5.0 simulator it throws error "class 'java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException' not found." in starting the application.

When I comment payment SDK code then application work fine.
after debuging I got following error at the starting point before application enter into the main() method.

```
Starting PaymentSdk
VM:LINK PaymentSdk
Class 'java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException' not found.
Linker error: 'VerifyError' for PaymentSdk
Error starting PaymentSdk: Class 'java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException' not found.
```

PaymentSdk is the name of application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SDK only works on 4.5 devices and above.

Comment: Did you mean to say 5.0 and up?

Comment: Nope. I was guessing he was using an OS way under 5.0: http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/21713/System_requirements_1249949_11.jsp

Comment: I know payment SDK is work on Os version 4.5 and above. I got Class 'java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException' not found. error in OS 4.5 and 4.7 simulator while same code work fine on 5.0 simulator.